# Does writing "Frame" as class paramter make the class into a frame, or does it just inherit from frame?

Tags: python, frame, inheritance

In python, if I write 
class SomeClass(Frame):
, does this mean that SomeClass actually becomes a Frame, or does it just inherit from Frame? I can't find a straight answer to this anywhere, every answer I find is very vague.

Comment: It inherits from `Frame`. What makes you think it might *be* a `Frame`?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

Comment: Ok thanks. Mostly I hoped for it, but also it seems like the class I'm in actually creates a frame and puts a lot of stuff in it, but maybe it's the line 'Frame._init_(self)' that does it.

Comment: Ye-es, if you call the parent initializer then that code is run too. `self` is still a `SomeClass` instance at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused - if something is an instance of a subclass, then it is also has all of the members of the superclass(es) and can be used in their place. In a very real sense, an instance of `SomeClass` is both an instance of `SomeClass` and also an instance of `Frame`.

```
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
...
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> isinstance(bar, Foo)
True
```